# Nodejs Express on Heroku App EACCES 0.0.0.0:80

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, express, heroku

I am trying to run a Node app on a newly created Heroku App from their web. I followed their steps and still I am getting errors when displaying app status.

I followed the [Node.js getting started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) section without the `heroku create` command since I already created from the web.

So when I run: `heroku ps:scale web=1` it shows me:

> Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free

But when running `heroku ps`:

> === web (Free): npm run start (1)
>
> web.1: crashed 2018/10/25 11:25:49 -0300 (~ 8m ago)

So my logs on `heroku logs --tail` show me this error:

> 2018-10-25T14:25:44.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
>
> 2018-10-25T14:25:46.451739+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run start`
>
> 2018-10-25T14:25:49.113832+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-10-25T14:25:49.113864+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-app@1.0.0 start /app
>
> 2018-10-25T14:25:49.113866+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
>
> 2018-10-25T14:25:49.113867+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-10-25T14:25:49.418151+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:167
>
> 2018-10-25T14:25:49.418191+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>
> 2018-10-25T14:25:49.418193+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
>
> 2018-10-25T14:25:49.418194+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-10-25T14:25:49.418196+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80

So I checked if I made a mistake while setting all up.

I use a simple Express routing and server with this code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => { ... });
app.listen(80, err => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("%c Server running", "color: green");
});
```

Also I made sure I added `engines` to **package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
},
"engines": {
    "node": "10.11.0",
    "npm": "6.4.1"
},
```

I've also created a **Procfile** file in the root path with `web: npm run start` inside.

So when everything is checked I just run these commands and everything looks great until I check the logs or visit the app:

```
git commit -am "my commit text"
git push heroku master
```

I see this in the logs:

> remote: -----> Compressing...
>
> remote:        Done: 18.3M
>
> remote: -----> Launching...
>
> remote:        Released v12
>
> remote:        https://my-app.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
>
> remote:
>
> remote: Verifying deploy... done.
>
> To https://git.heroku.com/my-app.git
>
> 3656da0..f1eb078  master -> master

So... Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to provide port for app to listen on in environment variable.
What heroku does is it runs our app on dynamic port.

Try using this:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, err => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("%c Server running", "color: green");
});
```

> Also you shouldn't bind the port to 80, as it is a reserved standard
>   http port.

Comment: Ok... it worked. Thank you. But I already tried with port 3000 and was the same. I was testing.

Comment: port 3000 is just in case if environment variable is undefined. Heroku assigns dynamic port to environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Heroku dynos expose a dynamic port for your app to bind to. This value is exposed in the $PORT env var. You must change your code to bind to this port instead.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, err => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("%c Server running", "color: green");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For modules solution ( "type": "module" in package.json):

```
const process = require('process');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```