# Node API will return results in development but not in production

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I have this MEAN-stack app that includes a very slow request. It's a GET method that requires up to 4 seconds to return the results (it involves complex calculations).

When the app is running in dev mode it works just fine:

1. Node will take the data from the DB
2. The calculations will be performed
3. The results are sent to the client (Angular) and displayed.

However, I've just found out while trying to deploy to heroku that it crashes, showing the following log:

```
GET https://myDomain.herokuapp.com/api/myDomain 503 (Service Unavailable) polyfills.b4abbdc2af0a63a7.js:1 

KO {headers: Ua, status: 503, statusText: 'Service Unavailable', url: 'https://myDomain.herokuapp.com/api/myDomain', ok: false, …}
```

Is it possible that heroku might be limiting the time that Node takes to return the results?

Comment: Did you look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160266/heroku-503-service-unavailable?

Comment: I didn't see that. However, I already had 0.0.0.0/0 in Atlas